# Is the dragon priest in Ironbind Barrow supposed to have no mask?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to a place called Ironbind Barrow and met a girl and a Mage there. The mage's name was Bee-ja. They wanted to get treasure out of Ironbind Barrow, but when we reached the treasure chest, a dragon priest appeared and started attacking me, so I killed him. He didn't have a dragon priest mask like the other (usually masked) dragon priests like Nahkriin. So is this dragon priest meant to have a mask or not?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with supporting details? (Perhaps why you expect him to have a mask?) It's hard to understand as is

Comment: Well I went to a place called ironbind barrow and there a I met a girl and a Mage the mages name was bee-ja and they wanted to get treasure out of ironbind barrow and when we reach the chest with the treasure in it the a dragon priest appeared and started attacking me so I killed him and he didn't have a dragon preist mask like the other dragon priests that have a mask such as nahkriin. So is this dragon priest ment to have a mask or not?

Comment: @Thedeadricwarrior, it's better to edit your question to contain more detail, rather than leaving a comment.  There's an edit link just above these comments that you can use to add this information to your question.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot about that :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Warlord Gathrik](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Warlord_Gathrik) is the boss of Ironbind Barrow, and depending on your level, he may appear as a dragon priest, although he may also be a Draugr Deathlord instead.

However, even if he spawns as a priest, he is not one of the dragon priests that carries a mask.

There are only a few dragon priests that carry masks, and they are:

- Hevnoraak
- Krosis
- Morokei
- Nahkriin
- Otar the Mad
- Rahgot
- Vokun
- Volsung

You may encounter other priests (named and unnamed) in your journeys, but other than these they will not carry masks.  The UESP page on [Undead](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Undead) contains a subsection on dragon priests, and has links to the locations of all of them.

Comment: Oh ok thanks :) I thought I may have  lost a dragon preist mask but obviously not :D ty

Comment: @Thedeadricwarrior, if the answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept - click the little check mark under the number on the left hand side.

Comment: Haha lol when I was reading the game guide and see a dragon priest without a mask I was like WTF?!?!?!?!?! But that makes sense